# Unable to recieve data from device in ibmiotin

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, node-red, watson-iot

I'm using my mobile phone as an IoT device and it does appears in the "Browse Devices" section in IBM Watson IoT platform. The events of this device are also getting recorded like below,

`{
    "d": {
        "id": "iotdemodev",
        "ts": 1572278167346,
        "lat": 12.921498,
        "lng": 80.1854588,
        "ax": -0.01,
        "ay": -0.03,
        "az": 0,
        "oa": 0,
        "ob": 0,
        "og": 0
    }
}`

Now in Node-RED I have used like below , the deployment has been successful however there is no message display in the debug. 
[image: Node-red configuration]

Comment: it looks like you connected the node to quickstart. Can you confirm that your device was not created on the IoT Platform?

Comment: @idan yes the device is not created in IoT platform. I access the url from my phone which requests to enter deviceid once i enter the details it appears as a connected device in IoT platform and the events are stored.

Comment: what application do you use on your mobile phone to simulate the IoT device?

Comment: @idan I use google chrome.

Comment: you use an MQTT client in chrome? Or use chrome to show the quickstart?

Comment: I use chrome to show quickstart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is some mixed information on what you are saying. 
Try the following:

1) Use this to simulate and IoT Device

https://quickstart.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/iotsensor/

2) After that, grab your device id from top right (e.g. fde7a936a947)

3) Go to https://quickstart.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com and add device id and press Go button: fde7a936a947

4) You now should see data coming into quickstart

5) Now in NodeRed (as per above screens) use the device id from 2) as fde7a936a947 into Device Id field

6) Data should show up now.

Based on your post "
I'm using my mobile phone as an IoT device and it does appears in the "Browse Devices" section in IBM Watson IoT platform...." I would say that you are actually using a registered device and in such case using quickstart you won't receive the events. You need to use registered device way.  As such, for the Authentication drop-down, select "API Key". This would make visible the "API Key" drop-down. Select the "Add new ibmiot..." from the drop down and add the API Key and api-token that you can generate from the Watson IoT Platform.